# Should I set charset/codepage when working with digits only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, character-encoding

I have a C# code that returns coordinates:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodePage="65001" CodeFile="codefile.aspx.cs" inherits="codefile" %>

Response.Write(coordinates());
```

It otuput something like this:

77.0444687 12.9120790

Do I need to set the CodePage="65001"?

Is that appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `CodePage` value of `"65001"` is the Windows implementation of UTF-8 and the default encoding for ASP.NET is UTF-8, then it is not necessary to use this `CodePage` value, but it is not inappropriate either. You are just restating the default value. I suppose if the default changes in newer versions of the .NET Framework, then explicitly stating this value would be more useful.

---

Read [Code Page Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

By default, all pages have anyway a `CodePage` that is first set on web.config of the system, then you may have change it on web.config on the site, and finally you can change it on the page declaration on top.

You do not need to change the code page for numbers, from the default of the system that is probably `UTF-8` encoding.